# Unwrapping gone wrong

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image

I've been facing a small artifact when unwrapping to an image.

On the right is the picture I am trying to unwrap and on the left is the image that has been generated.

For some reason the face I have selected hasn't been completely filled in. I have no idea why this is happening and why it is only happening for this specific face. On other meshes this material has unwrapped just fine.

Could anyone give me a hint?

[image: Showing the artifact I am facing.]

Comment: in the left image, I see 6 selected vertices, while in the right image, there are only 4, apparently. Could it be some overlapping geometry, somehow?